# How can I express such function as known functions or power series?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, recurrence-relations, power-series

$$\int_0^x \cfrac{1}{1+\int_0^t \cfrac{1}{2+\int_0^{t_1} \cfrac{1}{3+\int_0^{t_2} \cfrac{1}{\cdots} dt_3} dt_2} dt_1} dt =f(x)$$

$$\int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{n+h_{n+1}(t)}{d} t=h_n(x)$$

$$h'_n(x)(n+h_{n+1}(x))=1$$
$$h'_{n+1}(x)(n+1+h_{n+2}(x))=1$$

I need to find $ h_1(x)=f(x)$

Please help me how to express $f(x)$ as known functions or power series?

Thanks a lot for answers

Comment: As a general rule, it is bad to write $\int_0^x f(x) dx$, because there are two different usages of the variable $x$.  As a rule, it should be written as $\int_0^x f(t)dt$. It's a little harder to do that with your chained "continued-fraction-like" integration, perhaps...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I have editted my question. Thank you very much for advice.

Comment: I changed \frac to \cfrac in your continued fraction.  The difference between the appearances of the fraction before and after is a nice illustration of the utility of \cfrac.  It's easier to read now.

Comment: @MichaelHardy : Really it is so. Thanks a lot for format change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that additionally you require $h_n(0)=0$ for all $n$ (because $\int_0^0=0$).
This allows us to compute the power series of $h_1$ to arbitrary precision.
For example working down from $n=4$:
$$h_4(x)=O(x)$$
$$h_3'(x)=\frac1{3+O(x)}=\frac13+O(x)$$ 
$$h_3(x)=\frac13x+O(x^2)$$
$$h_2'(x) = \frac1{2+\frac13x+O(x^2)}=\frac12-\frac1{12}x+O(x^2)$$
$$h_2(x)=\frac12x-\frac1{24}x^2+O(x^3)$$
$$h_1'(x) = \frac1{1+\frac12x-\frac1{24}x^2+O(x^3)}=1-\frac12x+\frac7{24}x^2+O(x^3)$$
$$h_1(x) = x-\frac14x^2+\frac7{72}x^3+O(x^4)$$
Starting with $n=10$, I get
$$h_1(x) = x
 - \frac{1}{4} x^2
 + \frac{7}{72} x^3
 - \frac{149}{3456} x^4
 + \frac{21193}{1036800} x^5
 - \frac{235619}{23328000} x^6
 + \frac{1408454377}{274337280000} x^7
 - \frac{1227854784917}{460886630400000} x^8
 + \frac{6524483827239647}{4645737234432000000} x^9+ O(x^{10}).
$$
I don't know if the sequence of coefficients should be well-known.

Comment: thanks for answer. Can we find $\lim x-->\infty$ $f(x)$? Any suggestion?

Comment: I calculated the coefficients up to $x^{1000}$. Apparently they are alternating and their absolute value grows slowly (reaching about 0.59 there, if I remember yesterdays output correctly). It might still tend to $\phi$, $\frac23$, $1$ or $\infty$ - who knows?